# Pyserial failed to read full line after sending data

Tags: python, serial-port, microcontroller, pyserial

I'm developping a script with Pyserial to send data to a microcontroller, the microcontroller then read the data, process them, and send back some debug information to my python script.

My python script was working without any issue when i was just reading the data from the microcontroller. Now that I need to send data to the microcontroller and start reading just after that, the data i'm reading are not complete.

I should receive something like **[TAG1],10,11,12,[TAG1],13,14,15\n** but sometimes I don't received the beginning of the data but only the end like **1,12,[TAG1],13,14,15\n**

I'm basically doing:

```
serial.write(dataOut)
dataIn = serial.read(sizeOfTheDataToReceive)
```

The issue does not come from the microcontroller I'm sure of that, if I'm using putty to send/receive my data I always see the full data.

I tried to add some delay in my microcontroller code to send the data 10s after receiving the data from python, but still it's not working everytime.

Do you have any idea what can cause it ? The COM port is opened when the python script start and is closed at the end of the script.

Answer (score 0):

You need to clear your read and write buffers:

```
serial.flushInput()
serial.flushOutput()
```

Then read the data byte-wise:

```
serial.write(dataOut)
time.Sleep(0.3)
s=''
while serial.inWaiting()>0:
    b=serial.read(1)
#   time.Sleep(0.1)
    s += b
```

Comment: I tried that, included the two flush functions within a while(1) loop so that i can send, read; send, read;... Even with delays it's still not working, sometimes i missed a part of the incoming data.